# Perl Using a hash as a reference is deprecated when used with package

Tags: perl

I have a module called News (original name, I know) with a method called get_fields, this method returns all the fields that belong to the module like this

```
sub get_fields {
  my $self = shift;

  return $self;
}
```

Now when I call it like this in a different module where I need to do stuff to the fields

```
my %fields = %{ $news->get_fields };
```

I discovered doing it like this prevented this issue

> Type of argument to keys on reference must be unblessed hashref or
>   arrayref

when I iterate other fields like this

```
foreach my $key ( keys %fields ) {
  %pairs->{$key} = %fields->{$key} if %fields->{$key};
}
```

in order to use the values of the fields, I get this warning

> Using a hash as a reference is deprecated

which is pointing back to the foreach loop.

How can I avoid this error message without getting the unbless warning back?

Comment: Rule of thumb: the sigil (the `$%@` part of a variable) corresponds to what part of the variable you're working with.  It's `$foo{key}` and `$bar[23]` because you're accessing a single value, even though the variables are `%foo` and `@bar`. Not the best design, but at least there's a rule.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're getting mixed up between *objects* and *hashes*. `get_fields` will return `$self` - which whilst I can't tell for certain, looks like it'll be returning a blessed object.

Now, blessed objects are quite similar to hashes, but they're not the same. You can test the difference with the `ref` function.

So the question is more - *why* are you doing this? Why are you trying to cast an object reference into a hash? Because that's what you're doing with:

```
my %fields = %{ $news->get_fields };
```

Because pretty fundamentally - even if that worked, it would be a horrible thing to do. The point, purpose and reason for objects is encapsulation - e.g. things *outside* the module don't meddle with stuff *inside*.

So why not instead have `get_fields` return a list of fields, which you can then iterate on and make method calls? This would really be the 'right' way to do something like this.

```
sub get_fields {
    my ( $self ) = @_;
    return keys %$self; 
}
```

Or if you *really* must, embed a method within your object that returns as hash - rather than an object reference - that you can then manipulate externally.

Generally - you don't refer to hashes with a `%` prefix, unless you're manipulating the whole hash.

To extract a single element from `%pairs` you *should* do:

```
foreach my $key ( keys %pairs ) { 
    print $pairs{$key},"\n";
}
```

If the contents of `$pairs{$key}` is a reference, then you can use the `->` to indicate that you should dereference, e.g. `$pairs -> {$key}`.

Comment: thank you for the answer. The reason why I did return $self was in order to get the keys and the values of the object, instead of having getter/setter methods for each object property. But I agree, a more correct way would be using getters/setters or returning %pairs.

Comment: Thing is - OO imposes an overhead on your coding style. That overhead isn't _always_ a price worth paying. The reason we do OO at all is not because of efficiency, but because it makes code more robust and easier to troubleshoot, because problems are almost always within either the object or whatever is manipulating the object. This is a useful advantage, which is why OO is popular, but it only exists as long as we maintain the OO paradigm - if you mix and match, you get worst of both worlds. Some languages don't even allow you to do that - Perl does, but it remains bad style.

Comment: I agree, it's been more than 10 since I did Perl the last time, I've been working with a ton of other languages in the mean time, but thanks for the answer :)